# How to plot Log(P(x)) in a histogram?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have been using `SmoothHistogram` to plot the probability density function $P(x)$ of some experimental data. On the y-axis, I would like to have $\log(P(x))$ instead of $P(x)$. I do not want a log scale: the y-axis would have negative values. This is an example of code I have been using:

```
SmoothHistogram[Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {it, 1,10^5}], Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}]
```

Maybe I could try to extract information from `SmoothHistogram` and use `ListPlot`?

I've been using Mathematica 10.0 . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`"]
```

There is no need to use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) with [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) to generate multiple values.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^5];

SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}]
```

[image]

The distribution corresponding to [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html) is [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html)

```
Plot[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], x], {x, -4, 4}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}]
```

[image]

Plotting the [`Log`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) of the [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) is straightforward.

```
Plot[Log@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], x], {x, -4, 4}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Log(p(x))"}]
```

[image]